# Why is ActionCable rendering partials more than once?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I created a broadcast style notification system with actioncable. That simply renders a banner, after a post is created by a user. After every refresh, the banner shows again.

I tried setting a created_at constraint that only loads records created 5 seconds ago, and I limited the amount of records to 1 for the very last update. Even so, the constraint is ignored and the partial view is rendered anyway.

**notify_followers_controller**

```
class NotifyFollowersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    following_ids = current_user.following_users.pluck(:id)
    @notify_followers = NotifyFollower.where("created_at < ?", 5.seconds.ago).(user_id: following_ids).limit(1)
  end
end
```

**channels/post_follower_notifier.coffee**

```
App.post = App.cable.subscriptions.create PostChannel",
  connected: ->

  disconnected: ->

  received: (notify_follower) ->
# Called when there's an incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $(".post-notification-location").prepend "<div class='notify_follower'> #{notify_follower.message}</div>"
    window.setTimeout (->
      $('.alert').fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp 500, ->
        $(this).remove()
        return
      return
    ), 5000
```

**cable.js**

```
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `rails generate channel` command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function () {

    this.App || (this.App = {});

    App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery3
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

**post_channel.rb**

```
class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "post_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

**connection.rb**

```
module
  ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user && cookies.signed['user.expires_at'] > Time.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Expected results: The broadcast message should only render once after each post. Actual Results: The broadcast message renders after every refresh.

Comment: `"created_at < ?", 5.seconds.ago` means "records with created_at OLDER than 5 seconds ago". If you want the records created on the last 5 seconds then use `>` instead of `<`.

Comment: I'm getting this response in the server.  **NotifyFollower Load (184.9ms)  SELECT "notify_followers".* FROM "notify_followers" WHERE "notify_followers"."notification_read" = $1 AND (created_at < '2019-02-04 01:50:16.146732') AND "notify_followers"."user_id" = $2  [["notification_read", false], ["user_id", 2]]**

Comment: That's just the log of the query, not a response or anything (and you are still using the `<` which will match almos ALL records on your table EXCEPT the ones created on the last 5 seconds)

Comment: Hold on, has_many :notify_followers is not present in the user.rb

Comment: I think that I found the problem. I had the variable defined the same exact way in another controller. Its working now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Feel free to add the solution that you gave as the correct answer.